# Find all the uses of a metadata node

Tags: llvm

I have an `MDNode*` (found using `DebugInfoFinder`). I want to find out all the other `MDNode`s in the module that use it, but its use list appears to be empty. How do I find that?

For example, I have something like:

```
...
!5 = metadata !{i32 100}
...
!8 = metadata !{i32 101, metadata !5}
...
```

If I have `metadata !{i32 100}`, how do I get a reference to `metadata !{i32 101, metadata !5}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "use" of `!5` is `!8`, another `MDNode`, this is intentional.

A `MDNode` is not considered to be a "user"; note that while `Instruction` is-a `User`, `MDNode` is not. Metadata cannot affect code generation, by design. Had `MDNode` been a "user" of values, dead values whose only use is in metadata could not be killed, which goes against the design.

Pragmatically, this means that to perform interesting analyses on metadata you will need to construct this usage graph on your own from the module. If this sounds expensive, worry not because `DebugInfoFinder` already kind-of does this. So you can replace it with your own analysis (same cost) that collects more useful information.